# How to fix small GUI on Mendeley Desktop?

Tags: hdpi, mendeley

I installed [Mendeley desktop](https://www.mendeley.com/download-desktop/Linux/) on my laptop which has a high DPI screen (3200x1800). The GUI is extremely tiny and I've tried googling ways to force the GUI to be larger or adapt it for my screen to no avail. I really would like a way to make it larger as I will be using a lot and it will save my eyes from having to try to see very tiny buttons and text.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can upscale the entire interface---including fonts---by running Mendeley from terminal using the command

```
QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.2 mendeleydesktop
```

You can also play around with running it with the auto-scale factor on, using

```
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1 mendeleydesktop
```

This does not scale up the font, but seems to break look at pdf's. They also work in conjunction, but is till break looking at pdf's:

```
 QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1 QT_SCALE_FACTOR=0.7 mendeleydesktop
```

Comment: Works also for me. While I don't like the fact that now the fonts look ugly, this is better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

> QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1 QT_SCALE_FACTOR=0.7 mendeleydesktop

Thank you Rasmus, this worked for me.

To make it permanent I added to the `launch_mendeley_desktop()` method of the `/usr/bin/mendeleydesktop` file the following lines to set the environment variables:

```
os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
os.environ["QT_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "0.7"
```

Comment: I had a similar issue - after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 Mendeley had enormous fonts. Using QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.0 restored correct settings. I tried to make it permanent by putting it inside launcher file but it didn't help as somehow it got rewritten every time. Changing /usr/bin/mendeleydesktop (it's a python file) by adding os.environ["QT_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1.0" at the end of the set_environment function did the trick. Thanks IlBaroneRampante!